# Mixing Static and Dynamic Elements in Header

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am relatively new to angulerjs but using routes, services, controllers etc, I can develop a standard web application with a navbar header with pages appearing in an `ng-view` below it, i.e.

```
<body>

    <header>
        navbar goes here
    </header>

    <div class="content-wrapper" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

At the moment, everything that appears between the `<header>` tags is completely static and doesn't change regardless of what page is loaded within the `ng-view`.

I now need to add a number of items to the header which is contextual based on what page is in `ng-view`.

So, I'll have a single bar across the top of the site (like stackoverflow). It will contain two sub elements - one will be floated to the left and will be static, the other will be floated to the right and it's contents will be dynamic.

I'm unsure how to accomplish this in angularjs because I believe a page can only contain one `ng-view`

Any advice would be appreciated

EDIT: Adding following explanation:

To give a little more context, one of the DIVs in the header will contain contextual buttons. E.g. if the site is displaying a product item, the buttons in the header will be 'Edit', 'Delete'. If the site is displaying an invoice, the buttons in the header will be 'Add Product', 'Send Invoice'. My header is basically like Youtube's, if the buttons on the right changed based on the type of page being displayed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of exactly what you're trying to set in the header based on ng-view, and you may want to rethink some of the structure here if you're just starting out. In general, though, you can nest things a little differently to give you access to objects within `MainController`'s $scope:

```
<body>

    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <header>
            {{customHeader}}
        </header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div ng-view onload={{customHeader = 'something new'}}></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To give a little more context, one of the DIVs in the header will contain contextual buttons. E.g. if the site is displaying a product item, the buttons in the header will be 'Edit', 'Delete'. If the site is displaying an invoice, the buttons in the header will be 'Add Product', 'Send Invoice'. My header is basically like Youtube's, if the buttons on the right changed based on the type of page being displayed.

Comment: That's what I mean about rethinking your approach here. Why can't the header be a part of your `ng-view` template?

Comment: The other half of the header includes the site's logo and menu, both of which never change. Therefore, it doesn't seem right to be to have them in each ng-view template. Also, the ng-view templates will load with an animation, and I don't want the header to be animate at all with each page change.